# C# - set string as an EnumValue

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, toolstripdropdown

I have a `ToolStripMenu` with several `ToolStripDropDownButtons`. Those dropDownButtons have `ToolStripMenuItems` on themselves (sub buttons). I need to set visibility permission and the issue is that a user may have permissions only for some tsMenuItems or may be omitted from seeing all the item in a certain dropDownButton then the whole `ToolStripDropDownButtons` should be set to `Visible = false`.

The rights for the visibility are set in a public `Enum` like this:

```
[EnumValue("Clients")]
Clients = 1,

[EnumValue("Materials")]
Materials = 2,

[EnumValue("Uppers")]
```

and so on...

I started to write a method but the the logic it is based on is that each `ToolStripItem` is named just like the `EnumValue`. So what I need (if possible) is somehow to do that:

```
private void SetToolStripDropDownVisibility(ToolStripDropDown mainBtn, params ToolStripItem[] item)
        { 
            foreach (ToolStripItem tempItem in item)
            {
                EnumValue eValue = tempItem.Text;
                if (Helpers.GrantActivity(ControlEnum.eValue, ActionEnum.ShowMenuItem))
            }
        }
```

- First if possible is to use `tempItem.Text` as `EnumValue` what I tried here, but obviously need some casting or other - `EnumValue eValue = tempItem.Text;` and the call the helper method with a correct argument - `ControlEnum.eValue` which as it seems to me still depends on that if I can use `tempItem.Text` as `EnumValue`.

Comment: is that what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403065/how-can-i-assign-a-string-to-an-enum-instead-of-an-intereger-value-in-c/12403191#12403191

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand your code but I think I need exactly the opposite - I have the string (from the `tempItem.Text`) I need to use it as an `EnumValue`.

Comment: can't you use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

Comment: Here's Jon Skeet's answer on similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1033269/694852

Comment: I just find out that this exists. But looks like this is what I need. Still have to write some code. But if you want post it as answer. I think I'm gonna use it.

Comment: @Habib "That will do it for the name, not the description attribute." (C) Jon Skeet :)

Comment: @Artemix, there is no description attribute on the Enum, I believe the OP is trying to parse Enum from string.

Comment: @Leron, better if you use `Enum.TryParse` check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the string (from the tempItem.Text) I need to use it as an
>   EnumValue *(from comments)*

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) or [`Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx) method something like:

```
EnumValue enumValue;
if (Enum.TryParse<EnumValue>("Materials", out enumValue))
{
    //parsing successful
}
else
{
    //parisng failed. 
}
```

output:

```
enumValue = Materials
```

If your enum is defined as:

```
public enum EnumValue
{
    Clients = 1,
    Materials = 2,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, I have something similar in a project I did a few months back, it worked for me.

```
EnumValue enm = (EnumValue)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumValue), tempItem.Text);
```