# How to get value from description using Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like

```
public enum Test {a = 1, b, c, d, e }
```

and then I have a method where I pass 'a' as parameter but i need to retrieve corresponding value from enum and return `Integer` value from method

```
public int Getvalue(string text)        
{                
    int value = //Need to convert text in to int value.    
    return value;   
}
```

I am passing `text` as "a" or "b" or "c" but need 1, 2 or 3 as result. I have tried some solution found online but all seems to want me have `[Description]` tag added in enum to get value.

Is it possible to get value from description in enums in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1033260/2065121

Comment: @RogerRowland, the OP doesn't need description, so I don't think its a duplicate

Comment: @Habib - are you sure? Read  the possible duplicate again - it's almost identical.

Comment: @RogerRowland, I think not, OP is asking if adding description is neccessary ?, I don't think so, `Enum.Parse` can be used to parse string to enum and then get the value using simple casting.

Comment: @Habib - ok, my mistake, sorry - it's *not* a duplicate! I'll read more carefully next time...

Comment: @RogerRowland, don't worry, happens all the time, the question from the title looks very similar to the linked question.

Comment: @Habib - yes and annoyingly, according to meta, we *still* cannot rescind close votes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add the description tag, as long as you are passing the enum value as string, since `a`, `b`, exists in the enum, you can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) to parse string to Enum `Test` and then you can get the corresponding value like:

```
var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(Test), "a");
int integerValue = (int)value;
```

Or you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) which would not raise an exception in case of invalid input string. Like:

```
Test temp;
int integerValue;
if (Enum.TryParse("a", out temp))
{
    integerValue2 = (int)temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Framework >= 4.0 you can use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

```
public int GetValue(string text)
{
    Test t;
    if (Enum.TryParse(text, out t)
        return (int)t;       
    // throw exception or return a default value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic helper that gives you ability to get any type of enums int value

```
    public static int? GetValue<T>(string text)
    {
        var enumType = typeof (T);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            return null;

        int? val;
        try
        {
            val = (int) Enum.Parse(enumType, text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            val = null;
        }

        return val;
    }
```